# Python Dataframe using Columns as Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder

I am relatively new to Python and I've run in to a problem that I cannot seem to search my way out of.  I have written a function to query a third-party API. The function runs as expected and retrieves the correct results.  However, my dataframe display returns the results with my columns and rows transposed.  I have used this same function before without issue.  I know I can transpose them to the correct position, but since I want to use this function as part of a larger function it is important that the query return the values with the columns and rows as intended.

I've included my snippet below as well as the results and desired outcome.

```
import pandas as pd

def get_tiering():
    df = vendorAPI.getportfoliocustomcolumns('prod').as_dataframe()
    records = df.to_dict('records')
    return {rec['Patient']: rec for rec in records}

tiersdf = pd.DataFrame(get_tiering())

print(tiersdf)
```

[image: current output]

[6 rows x 198 columns]

[image: desired output]

[198 rows x 6 columns]

I am wondering if there is some DataFrame setting that I inadvertently changed? I am using Spyder version 2.2 with Python 3.9.  Any guidance you can provide would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `tiersdf.T`?

This is my sample df

```
        p1  p2  p3
height  65  66  5
weight  62  22  6
age     32  55  8
bp      12  44  6
hr      2   8   3
```

and i got this after doing transform

```
     height weight  age bp  hr
p1    65    62      32  12  2
p2    66    22      55  44  8
p3     5    6       8   6   3
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, XXavier. Yes, I tried that however since I need to feed the results of this function to another function the transpose option is not a viable solution for me in this instance.

Comment: I do not understand why you cannot pass this transformed data or transform it after you pass the dictionary??

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try to change

```py
records = df.to_dict('records')
return {rec['Patient']: rec for rec in records}
```

to

```py
return df.transpose().to_dict('series')
```

Please, let me know if it works. Otherwise, please let us know the exact output of `vendorAPI.getportfoliocustomcolumns('prod')`

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, @Alex.  Tried your change, but I still get the same output.  I am sorry, I do not know how to add it to my comment but the current output is included in my original post.

Comment: If I am not wrong the output in your original post belongs to this ```pd.DataFrame(get_tiering())```. But it's critical to see what ```vendorAPI.getportfoliocustomcolumns('prod')``` returns before you apply your changes within your function...